# Usage of word white in context and alone

Tags: translation, word-choice, meaning, syntax

Could anyone explain the difference in the meaning of word white written using following kanji or Kana?

1. 白い,
2. しろ,
3. しろい.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning between 白い and しろい. Both are an adjective that can be used attributively and predicatively as in:

> 白い花 White flower
>
> 肌が白い Skin is white.

You can read the [Wikipedia article on Japanese writing system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_writing_system) to understand which one to use in writing. Basically, kana is used when there is no corresponding kanji.

[白 and しろ](http://jisho.org/search/shiro) are a noun.

> 白を着る Wear a white (clothes)

It can be used as a noun modifier before another noun, for example:

> 白シャツ White shirt